# How do I implement the area calculator using latitude and longitueds

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can any one help me , How do I implement the area calculator using in group of latitude and longitudes .

For Example One person walk around the building , I am getting the latitude and longitudes while walking time . I want calculate the how much square feet that building was constructed.

Comment: How about trying something yourself and then asking about a specific problem that appears?!

Comment: Thank you give the valuable advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I´m going to try to help you, but I´m not going to give the complete answer.

I think, the first step is convert lats and longs in a cartesian coordinate system. You should calculate the center of all points. (A simple median).

Second step, convert all points to ENU coordinates centered in its center: 
[image]

This step, I did, and here you are:

Constants:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS (M_PI/180.0)

#define WGS84_A (6378137.0)             // WGS 84 semi-major axis constant in meters
#define WGS84_E (8.1819190842622e-2)    // WGS 84 eccentricity
```

Structs:

```
 //To change to ECEF
 typedef struct{
double x;
double y;
double z;

 } ECEFCoordinate;

typedef struct{
double east;
double north;
double up;

} ENUCoordinate;
```

Methods, (you need past through ECEF):

#pragma mark Geodetic utilities definition

```
-(ECEFCoordinate) ecefFromLatitude:(double)lat longitude:(double)lon andAltitude:(double)alt
 {
double clat = cos(lat * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
double slat = sin(lat * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
double clon = cos(lon * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
double slon = sin(lon * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);

double N = WGS84_A / sqrt(1.0 - WGS84_E * WGS84_E * slat * slat);

ECEFCoordinate ecef;
ecef.x = (N + alt) * clat * clon;
ecef.y = (N + alt) * clat * slon;
ecef.z = (N * (1.0 - WGS84_E * WGS84_E) + alt) * slat;

return ecef;
}
// Converts ECEF to ENU coordinates  centered at given lat , lon (with ECEFCenter)
 -(ENUCoordinate)enuFromECEFCenter:(ECEFCoordinate)ecefCenter withLat:(double)lat andLon:(double)lon fromEcef:(ECEFCoordinate)ecef
{
double clat = cos(lat * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
double slat = sin(lat * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
double clon = cos(lon * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
double slon = sin(lon * DEGREES_TO_RADIANS);
double dx = ecefCenter.x - ecef.x;
double dy = ecefCenter.y - ecef.y;
double dz = ecefCenter.z - ecef.z;

ENUCoordinate enu;
enu.east = -slon*dx  + clon*dy;
enu.north = -slat*clon*dx - slat*slon*dy + clat*dz;
enu.up = clat*clon*dx + clat*slon*dy + slat*dz;

return enu;
}
```

Last step: (I think the easy way is use triangles, from center to two consecutive points), calculate the area of a bunch of points in a cartesian coordinate system (east,north). Same than (x,y).

Good luck.

Last help two calculate the Area, I think you can find more help (and maybe best way) trough internet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Onik  Spent the your valuable time for me & give the replay  ,

Comment: Onik , I am follow the your inputs , Finally i got bunch of ENU Points (east , north , up) and Center is ECEFCoordinate. After that i calculate the lenghts (L1,L2....Ln) and Angles (alpha1 , alpha 2,...alphan). this is wirte

Comment: After that calculate the piece of Triangles areas (A1,A2....An), final Area = A1+A2..An this is right